# Does VS2010 support 'controlling compiler-generated functions'?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
class NonCopyable
{
public:
    NonCopyable() = default;
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator=(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
};
```

I have tried the above code with VS2010 and it doesn't pass the compilation.

```
1>c:\temp\app1\app1\app1.cpp(12): error C2065: 'default' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\temp\app1\app1\app1.cpp(12): error C2253: 'NonCopyable' : pure specifier or abstract override specifier only allowed on virtual function
1>c:\temp\app1\app1\app1.cpp(13): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\temp\app1\app1\app1.cpp(13): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\temp\app1\app1\app1.cpp(14): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\temp\app1\app1\app1.cpp(14): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Question> As far as I know, `default` and `delete` are new features for C++0x.
Does VS2010 support those new standard?

// updated -- it is supported with gcc version 4.5.2 //

// gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)

```
$ ~/Documents/C++ $ g++ -o t2 t2.cpp -std=c++0x
```

Comment: It's also not supported int eh VS11 Developer Preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sadly VC2010 does not. It doesn't even support automatically generated move constructors.

[Here is a list of C++11 features VC2010 supports.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx) Note that some of them are only partially supported.

Comment: Note that the Visual C++ 11 Developer Preview does fully support the implicitly defined move operations (it does not support defaulted or deleted special members, however).